# conditional run report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

what I need to complete: My report has a parameter: A or B.  When A the report run table A.  when B report run table A and table B (but when exported to Excel, table A will show up in sheet1, table B will show up in sheet2).

the problem:  when choose parameter to A, the table A run, table B not show but exported to excel, still show sheet2 as a blank page with report header.

So far, I put condition on visibility to table B to conditionally show table B.  and change a report properties (ConsumeContainerWhitespace = True)

how to get rid of the extra sheet when only run TableA?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for the last Tablix on the report (which is expected to be the last worksheet upon exporting to excel) - set the Page Break > Break Location = None.